# How do you make the Frame control's Arrows and Nav Tab bigger?

Tags: wpf

I have a Wpf `Frame` control. I can't find any property that will make the back/forward nav arrows change size so they are easier to touch on a tablet. Does such a thing exist? Could I use a style for it without having to completely reimplement the `Frame` UI styling? [image]

```
<Frame Source="Pages/Login.xaml" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works, albeit not as well polished looking as desired.

[full C# and F# code examples](https://gist.github.com/ImaginaryDevelopment/0377960c53f679626167ad8f309fa7ed)

[image: Output]

### FSharp

```
let fixArrowSize (frame:Frame) =
    let adjustGridControl size (c:Control) =
        c.MinHeight <- size
        c.MinWidth <- size
        c
        |> Option.ofCast<Button>
        |> Option.iter(fun b ->
            let content = b.Content
            let child = getTemplateChild b :?> Grid
            child.MinHeight <- size
            child.MinWidth <- size
        )
    match getDockPanel frame with
    | null -> ()
    | dp ->
        let grid =
            dp
            |> getChildrenOfType<Grid>
            |> Seq.head
        grid
        |> getChildrenOfType<System.Windows.Shapes.Path>
        |> Seq.tryHead
        |> Option.iter (fun path ->
            grid.Children.Remove path
            let size = 40.0
            grid
            |> getChildrenOfType<Control>
            |> Seq.iter (adjustGridControl size)
        )
    ()
```

### CSharp

```
static void FixArrowSize(Frame frame)
{
    var dp = GetDockPanel(frame);
    if (dp is null)
        return;
    var grid = dp.Children.OfType<Grid>().FirstOrDefault();
    var path = grid.Children.OfType<System.Windows.Shapes.Path>().FirstOrDefault();
    // we did it, we're going to be called multiple times, but only need to do our job once
    if (path == null)
        return;
    grid.Children.Remove(path);
    var size = 40.0;

    grid.Children.OfType<Control>().ToList().ForEach(c =>
    {
        c.MinHeight = size;
        c.MinWidth = size;
        if (c is Button b)
        {
            var content = b.Content;
            var child = GetTemplateChild(b) as Grid;
            child.MinHeight = size;
            child.MinWidth = size;
        }
    });
    var cd = grid.ColumnDefinitions;
    cd[0].Width = new GridLength(size);
    cd[1].Width = new GridLength(size);
    // no row definitions
    var rd = grid.RowDefinitions;
    grid.MinHeight = size;
}
```